# Set custom font on SwiftUI TextField

Tags: swiftui

How could I set a custom font for the TextFiled so I don't have to specify it each instance. Applying .font to the .textFieldStyle does not work.

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Oval Custom TextField Style").font(.title2)
            HStack {
                TextField("Search...", text: $text)
            }
            .textFieldStyle(OvalTextFieldStyle())
        }.padding()
```

Comment: Not really clear what you would like to achieve, could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```swift
 HStack {
    TextField("Country...", text: $country)
        .textFieldStyle(TextFieldDarkFull())
    TextField("Phone...", text: $phone)
        .textFieldStyle(TextFieldDarkFull())
 }
 .font(.displaySmall())
```

Comment: Builds, but no impact on the font. 

HStack {
          TextField("Country...", text: $country)
            .font(.displaySmall())
            .textFieldStyle(TextFieldDarkFull())

Comment: Tested with a 2nd field omitting the .font() modifier and both fonts are the same.  

HStack {
          TextField("Country...", text: $country)
            .font(.displaySmall())
            .textFieldStyle(TextFieldDarkFull())
          TextField("Phone...", text: $phone)
            .textFieldStyle(TextFieldDarkFull())